# Laravel 5.4: slow loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, optimization, eager-loading

I have problem with slow load: almost 10 seconds. I guess I have to optimize the code in some way, but I don't know how. Any help? Thanks.

This is the **controller**. I use the trait ListNoticias (below the controller).

```
class NoticiaController extends Controller
{
use ListNoticias;

public function actualidad(Request $request)
{
    $data['section_id'] = explode(',', '1,2,3');

    $data['ruta'] = 'actualidad';
    $data['title'] = __('header.actualidad');
    $data['num'] = $request->num;
    $url = $request->url();

    $data = $this->listNoticias($data, $url);

    return view('web.actualidad.listado', compact('data'));
}
}
```

And this is the **trait**. Here, I collect a list of all the news in three different arrays for each of the languages and then I manually paginate them.

```
trait ListNoticias
{
public function listNoticias($data, $url)
{
    $now = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    (isset($data['num']))? $num = $data['num'] : $num = '15';

    $data['images'] = Image::where('imageable_type', 'App\Models\Noticia')->get();
    $data['sections']  = Section::all();

    $data['noticias'] = Noticia::where('date', '<', $now)
        ->where('active', '1')
        ->whereIn('section_id', $data['section_id'])
        ->orWhere('date', '=', $now)
        ->where('time', '<=', $time)
        ->where('active', '1')
        ->whereIn('section_id', $data['section_id'])
        ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('time', 'desc')
        ->get();

    $data['noticias-es'] = [];
    $data['noticias-en'] = [];
    $data['noticias-pt'] = [];

    foreach($data['noticias'] as $row){
        foreach($row->langs as $row_lang) {
            if ($row_lang->lang_id == '1') {
                $data['noticias-es'][] = $row;
            } elseif ($row_lang->lang_id == '2') {
                $data['noticias-en'][] = $row;
            } elseif ($row_lang->lang_id == '3') {
                $data['noticias-pt'][] = $row;
            } else null;

        }
    }

    // Manual paginate
    /*  Get current page form url e.x. &page=1
        Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
        Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
        Create our paginator and pass it to the view
        set url path for generated links
    */

    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    // ES
    $itemCollection = collect($data['noticias-es']);
    $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $num) - $num, $num)->all();
    $data['noticias-es'] = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $num);
    $data['noticias-es']->setPath($url);

    // EN
    $itemCollection = collect($data['noticias-en']);
    $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $num) - $num, $num)->all();
    $data['noticias-en'] = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $num);
    $data['noticias-en']->setPath($url);

    // PT
    $itemCollection = collect($data['noticias-pt']);
    $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $num) - $num, $num)->all();
    $data['noticias-pt'] = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $num);
    $data['noticias-pt']->setPath($url);

    return $data;

}
}
```

**EDITED WITH MORE INFO**

Following the advice of the comments, I found one of the main problems in the following view, where I call the images of each news item to show it in the list along with the url and the slug. This I have done creating a foreach inside another. Is there any way to do it without nesting foreachs? Thank you.

The **partial view** with the image and url and slug:

```
@foreach($new->langs as $new_lang)
  @if($new_lang->lang_id == $lang_id)

    @foreach($data['images'] as $image)
        @if($image->imageable_id == $new->id && $image->main == '1')

            @php
                $mini = substr($image->path, 0, strrpos( $image->path, "/"));
                $name = substr($image->path, strrpos($image->path, '/') + 1);
                $image_mini = $mini.'/mini-'.$name;
            @endphp

            <div class="crop">
                <a href="{{ route('noticia', [$new->id, $new_lang->slug]) }}">
                    {{ HTML::image(file_exists($image_mini)? $image_mini : $image->path, '', array('class' => 'img-responsive ancho_100')) }}
                </a>
            </div>

        @endif
    @endforeach

  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: You can use debugbar to check which process using more time to complete

Comment: two `foreach` is good enough to break things, perhaps we should start there. like, why its needed what is the current table structure, what is the desired output..

Comment: Thanks Samir. The longest process is 322.66ms `select * from `images` where `imageable_type` = 'App\Models\Noticia'` Is this much? On the other hand there are 6284 queries, since it goes through the entire table lang_noticias Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Thanks Bagus Tesa. You are right, i´m going to see how to eliminate one…

Comment: If you're doing 6284 queries, it's normal it takes this long.
Try reduce the amount of queries (this might help https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Thanks Wouter Van Damme. Now I have only 4 querys but still is very slow: ten seconds. I´m going to see the views too.

Comment: I updated my question with more information.